# perl multithreading issue for autoincrement

Tags: perl

I'm writing a multi threaded perl script and storing the output in a csv file. I'm trying to insert a field called sl.no. in the csv file for each row entered but as I'm using threads, the sl. no. overlaps in most. Below is an idea of my code snippet.

```
for ( my $count = 1 ; $count <= 10 ; $count++ ) {
    my $t = threads->new( \&sub1, $count );
    push( @threads, $t );
}

foreach (@threads) {
    my $num = $_->join;
}

sub sub1 {
    my $num = shift;

    my $start = '...';    #distributing data based on an internal logic
    my $end   = '...';    #distributing data based on an internal logic
    my $next;

    for ( my $x = $start ; $x <= $end ; $x++ ) {
        my $count = $x + 1;

        #part of code from which I get @data which has name and age

        my $j = 0;
        if ( $x != 0 ) {
            $count = $next;
        }
        foreach (@data) {
            #j is required here for some extra code
            flock( OUTPUT, LOCK_EX );
            print OUTPUT $count . "," . $name . "," . $age . "\n";
            flock( OUTPUT, LOCK_UN );
            $j++;
            $count++;

        }
        $next = $count;
    }

    return $num;
}
```

I need the count to be incremented which is the serial number for the rows that would be inserted in the csv file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, you did `OUTPUT->autoflush(1)`, right?

Comment: ...Your lock is useless without it.

Comment: Hi, no, I didn't autoflush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already providing mutual exclusion using `flock`, so might as well take advantage of it if that's the only place `$count` is used.

```
my $counter :shared;  # Once for all threads
for (@data) {
    ...
    flock( OUTPUT, LOCK_EX );
    print OUTPUT ++$count . "," . $name . "," . $age . "\n";
    flock( OUTPUT, LOCK_UN );
 }
```

Or we can switch to just using Perl locks.

```
my $counter :shared;  # Once for all threads
for (@data) {
    ...
    {
       lock $counter;
       print OUTPUT ++$count . "," . $name . "," . $age . "\n";
    }
 }
```

In both cases, the lines in the output file will be numerical order.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $counter :shared;
$counter = 1;

sub nextValue() {
  lock $counter;
  return $counter++;
}
```

And then just call `nextValue()` in your code.  This will insure that only one thread at a time increments the shared counter.

Comment: If the goal is to for the numbers in the output file to be ever increasing, this won't work. It will only make sure the numbers in the file are unique.

Comment: @ikegami the my $counter :shared goes before any threads are spawned and is shared by all threads.

Comment: Of course it does. Doesn't change what I said. (T1:nextValue  T2:nextValue, T2:print, T1:print)

Comment: good point, but as you pointed out, there's already a flock in there that would have serialized those calls, so still not wrong :)  Your solution is better explained though.

Comment: If you call `nextValue` from within the flock block, then yes, it's fine. But then you don't need `nextValue` at all.